# Does the Regulation NMS Order Protection Rule apply to odd lots?

Tags: united-states, stocks, sec, order-execution

The [order protection rule](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/17/242.611) prohibits trade-throughs of NMS stocks during regular trading hours, but does the prohibition apply to odd lots too? If I decide to bid $408,500 for 1 share of Berkshire Hathaway class A, will the order protection rule ensure that no orders below my bid will get a fill before I get a fill?

Comment: Here is an article that might help: https://www.tradersmagazine.com/departments/commentary/nms-ii-an-odd-solution-for-the-odd-lot-problem

Comment: @SRiverNet-reinstatemonica I do not completely understand the article. From my understanding, the answer is "no", but the regulations might soon change.

Comment: that's what I gathered from it as well.